# Is there a software that can reverse calculate checksums by brute force?

Tags: crc, checksum

For reverse calculation of CRC checksums, there is a pretty nice tool – [CRC reveng](https://reveng.sourceforge.io/).

I was looking for, and have not found, a similar tool that can do the same for **non CRC** checksums. For example, using Xor, Sum, bit-shift action for the single bits or nibbles to get the given checksum.

Does anyone know about such a tool that can do this job?

[In my case](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/29991/finding-method-for-checksum-calculation-crc-or-xor-or-other) I have just 5 nibbles of data that are calculated into 1 nibble of checksum, but there is an algorithm behind which I was not able to reverse by myself. And I have a large set of data that can be used to accept or refuse proposed algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

The OA Labs [hashdb](https://github.com/OALabs/hashdb) project has a general framework for this, though it's primarily aimed at strings. Nonetheless, it does have a hefty list of [algorithms](https://github.com/OALabs/hashdb/tree/main/algorithms) implemented and an easy way to run them against data that might be useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

There’s this project which has a few more variations beyond CRC:

https://github.com/8051Enthusiast/delsum